# json-schema : Get a list of additionalProperties?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

Is it possible to get a list of all `additionalProperties` found by json-schema ?

For example, if my schema looks like this :

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

And data loooks like this :

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21,
  "extraField": "some new data I was not expecting",
  "anotherExtraField": "another unexpected data point"
}
```

In this case, instead of an exception from json-schema because of `additionalProperties: false`, I want a list in return, like : `[extraField, anotherExtraField]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an implementation that supports 2019-09 or 2020-12 with annotations, you're in luck!  `additionalProperties` should produce an annotation result of the properties it validates ([spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.10.3.2.3)).

If you add `additionalProperties: true`, then all extra properties pass and are validated by the keyword, which means those extra properties should be listed in the annotation result.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

This yields (in the `Detailed` output format)

```json
{
  "valid": true,
  "keywordLocation": "#",
  "instanceLocation": "#",
  "annotations": [
    {
      "valid": true,
      "keywordLocation": "#/properties",
      "instanceLocation": "#",
      "annotation": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "age"
      ]
    },
    {
      "valid": true,
      "keywordLocation": "#/additionalProperties",
      "instanceLocation": "#",
      "annotation": [
        "extraField",
        "anotherExtraField"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can try it on https://json-everything.net, which is powered by my validator, [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/).

If you're not using .Net, you can browse the [implementations page](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html) for other libraries.  Some of them may also support annotations, but I'm not sure which do.